# Report Builder page break Issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using report builder 3.0. I have a report which has a space at the start, just above the tablix. My tablix repeats for every page after page break, I need the space at the start to also repeat for every page along with the tablix. Please help me.

**Current Result:-**

Page 1:-

--space

--page1 data

Page 2:-

--page data

**Expected Result:-**

Page 1:-

--space

--page1 data

Page 2:-

--space

--page data

Comment: Why not put the space inside the Tablix? This way you will get it on all pages like you want

Comment: Yeah. It worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I'll put that as an answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put the space inside the Tablix? This way you will get it on all pages like you want